# Assigning value to the variable based on the request

Tags: jmeter

I have created a jmeter script as below

I am using the user defined variable with `function __P()` and passing the Url from .sh file

[image]

[image]

My requirement is, if the url passed is **"www.abc.com"** then set the value of the variable `${Prefix}` to "foo" else set it to "bar"

I tried using JSR223 PostProcessor, but JSR223 PostProcessor has to have a sample associated with it.
Any suggestion how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler directly:

```
${__groovy(if (vars.get('Url') == 'www.abc.com') {return 'foo'} else {return 'bar'},Prefix)}
```

[image]

For subsequent requests (once the __groovy() function has been run) you will be able to use just `${Prefix}`

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

If you're not too comfortable with Groovy scripting you can consider using [__if() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#ifsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-3-0-font-sup), it's a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle, can be installed usign [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T Thanks for the reply. Groovy function worked. I am parameterizing the request and going to pull the list of all the requests from the csv file. So, I believe, in that case as well, from the 2nd request, it will not execute the the groovy function again and will use the ${Prefix} value evaluated in 1st request, right? Also, can you give example of  __if() function if I were to use in this case?  Thanks again for your solution.

Comment: Hi @dmitri Thanks for the reply. Groovy function worked. I am parameterizing the request and going to pull the list of all the requests from the csv file. So, I believe, in that case as well, from the 2nd request, it will not execute the the groovy function again and will use the ${Prefix} value evaluated in 1st request, right? Also, can you give example of __if() function if I were to use in this case? Thanks again for your solution.